# Quorum: How to find the key used in privateFor

Tags: quorum, public-key, privacy, quorum-maker

I have a 3 nodes quorum network, which I created with the help of quorum maker. I am adding an new account to my first node, so that my first node now has 2 accounts on it. I want to find the public key that is required for the privateFor field for this new account. How do I go about doing it? I got the file in the keystore folder by I am not able to find the public key in the format required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was looking up for the wrong information. We don't need the account keys but instead needed the key from my constellation node key.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not enable the **TLS** in Tessera Node and all the nodes are placed within one host, then you can curl the ThirdParty server that holds all the public keys of the Tessera Nodes. Use the following command:

```
curl http://localhost:9001/partyinfo
```

The IP `localhost` and port `9001`, is the port where the Tessera node is listening according to the `quorum-examples`. The `IP` and the `port` can be changed accordingly, depending on your network setup.